# Could not load File or Assembly Microsoft.ReportDesigner V = 10.0.0.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Im using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, I have `Report Viewer 11.0.0.0` available, but I want to use the `10.0.0.0` so Under the toolbox **Reporting tab** I right click **'Choose Items'** I search `Report Viewer 10.0.0.0` I add the control, and also References to `Report Viewer 10.0.0.0`.

And when I drag the report viewer onto the form the following error says :

```
Failed to create component Report Viewer.
System.IO.FileLoadException. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportDesigner Version = 10.0.0.0, culture = neutral '
```

Comment: See [Winforms Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportDesigner, Version=10.0.0.0' in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287310/winforms-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-reportdesigner-version-10-0).  Also, try VS 2010 and/or VS 2008.